# getParamCached in rospy?

Tags: ros, rospy, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there a version of getParamCached() in rospy?

In roscpp: "ros::NodeHandle::getParamCached() and ros::param::getCached() provide local caching of parameter data. Using these versions informs the Parameter Server that this node would like to be notified when the parameter is changed, and prevents the node from having to re-lookup the value with the parameter server on subsequent calls."

If not, what would it take to implement it?

I am calling rospy.get_param() in a tight loop. I get some exceptions from httplib (CannotSendRequest and ResponseNotReady). Is it because I am calling get_param() too often? What over exceptions should I look for?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35262/getparamcached-in-rospy?/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2012-05-30

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know of a `rospy` implementation analogous to `getParamCached()`. Maybe there is one.

Another option, which definitely works with `rospy` is [dynamic_reconfigure](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure). It is easy to program in Python and offers several advantages over the basic ROS parameter server.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Siegfried Gevatter](https://answers.ros.org/users/1599/siegfried-gevatter/) on 2014-02-05**:
Actually, in rospy all parameter accesses are cached automatically. Not sure about the errors though.

Correction: ignore my message, there is some code for caching but it's disabled (eg. https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/hydro-devel/clients/rospy/src/rospy/msproxy.py line 114).